# How to extract data (title, email link, location) from first 10 pages using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

It is a public website containg data of compaines in Sweden. I want to extract data like (Title of companies, Email Link and Location ) from first 10 pages. I write code but it does not provide right result so please help me out. Thank you!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    if not response.ok:
        print('server responded:', response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml') # 1. html , 2. parser
    return soup

def get_detail_data(soup):

    try:
        title = (soup.find('h1',class_="Name",id=False).text)
    except:
        title = 'empty'
    try:
        address = (soup.find('p','font', class_=False,id=False).text)

    except:
        address = 'No location'
    try:
        email = soup.select_one("a[href^='mailto:']").get("href").split("mailto:")[1]

    except:
        email = 'No email'

    data = {
    'title'   : title,
    'address' : address,
    'email'   : email
    }
    return data
def get_index_data(soup):
    try:

        titles_link = soup.find_all('div',  {'class': 'Name'})
        for title in titles_link:
            link = soup.find('a',  {'title': title.text}).get('href')
            titles = ('https://www.118100.se' + link)

    except:
        titles_link = []
    return titles


def main():
    url = "https://www.118100.se/sok/foretag/?q=brf&loc=&ob=rel&p=0"
    #get_page(url)
    #get_detail_data(get_page(url))
    products = get_index_data(get_page(url))
    for product in products:
        data = get_detail_data(get_page(product))
        print(data)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the function  `get_index_data`. You are not returning a list, you are returning a single link. 
You should convert the variable `titles` in a list. For example:

```
def get_index_data(soup):
    titles = []
    try:
        titles_link = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'Name'})
        for title in titles_link:
            link = soup.find('a', {'title': title.text}).get('href')
            titles.append('https://www.118100.se' + link)
    except:
        return []
    return titles
```